# Rails: Calculate days between date range given in string format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

How could I calculate days from a given date range in Rails Controller. 
Example:

```
daterange = "August 24 - Sept 11, 2016"

Desired output: 19
```

Also we have to keep in mind that the date range string may also change to something:

```
"December 24 2016 - Jan 11, 2017"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(daterange.split("-")[1].to_date -  daterange.split("-")[0].to_date).to_i + 1

# daterange = "August 24 - Sept 11, 2016"
# => 19

# daterange = "December 24 2016 - Jan 11, 2017"
# => 19
```

Comment: Can I catch exception for the same expression in case daterange could not be able to format as expected

Comment: You can bind it in a `begin` `rescue` block to catch the exception.

Comment: there is another format also for the date range for which the above expression isn't working: "August 24 - 27, 2016"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def day_difference(daterange)
  daterange.split('-').map(&:to_date).inject { |r,e| (e-r).to_i + 1 }
end
```

With your given examples:

```
day_difference("August 24 - Sept 11, 2016")    
# => 19

day_difference("December 24 2016 - Jan 11, 2017")
# => 19
```